# Javascript - Can someone explain to me exactly what this does?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I started in a new company about 9 months ago now and keep coming across this in the JS. It works and I've been using it to keep in line with the previous developers way of writing code, but I don't exactly know what it does. I've tried googling it, but not sure exactly what to search for.

`!options && (options = {})`

To me, it feels like it's a sort of ternary conditional but I'm not too sure.

A better example of this would be:

```
function init(options) {
  !options && (options = {});
}

init();
```

Comment: If `options` is truthy (exists) nothing happens. If it's falsey (doesn't exist) `options` is created as an empty object.

Comment: it just creates the options object if it doesn't exist and assigns it.

Comment: It is equivalent to `options = options || {};`

Comment: The technical term for && is short-circuiting.

Comment: No it does not create an options object. Because there is only a pointer that will be overwritten inside the function. Outside the function the options object still is not visibile.

Comment: Good to see some good guys upvoted this poor guy's question after its been downvoted badly. Damn elite overflow

Comment: @DevMoutarde It is sad to see a question site rejecting well structured, well researched questions. How would OP have been able to search for this? They've done as much homework as possible, asked a question and been downvoted for it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is equivalent to:

```
if(!options)
  options = {};
```

This is an example of operator short-circuiting: the second expression (`options = {}`) will only be evaluated if the first expression (`!options`) is true, because if the first expression is false, the whole `&&`-statement would be automatically false.

This happens specifically when using the "and" (`&&`) and "or" (`||`) operators.

MDN has [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) describing this in more detail.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks a lot for answering this dude! I thought it was as simple as being a conditional statement, but the `&&` threw me off completely :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's a way of initialising `options` as `{}` if no value is given for it.

The first check, `!options`, means "options is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy)".

So, if `options` is `null`, `undefined`, etc, it will continue through the `&&` statement and set `options = {}`, initialising it.

It can be written as this, which is much clearer:

```
if (!options) {
    options = {};
}
```